# Error while installing pygit2

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, github, pygit2

I have to install pygit2 library on my ubuntu machine. I get the below error when I try "pip install pygit2".

cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pygit2
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

Prior to this, I did the following which went fine (http://www.pygit2.org/install.html#quick-install).

```
$ wget https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/archive/v0.22.0.tar.gz
$ tar xzf v0.22.0.tar.gz
$ cd libgit2-0.22.0/
$ cmake .
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I already have libffi6 on my machine .

```
sudo apt-get install libffi6 libffi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libffi-dev is already the newest version.
libffi6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install the libffi and the its' developing packages,which the pygit2 depends on

Comment: I already have it installed on my machine.                       sudo apt-get install libffi6 libffi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libffi-dev is already the newest version.
libffi6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.